# Different method of solving a question giving different answer

Tags: concentration, stoichiometry, mole

> Calculate the concentration of nitric acid in moles per litre in a sample which has a density, $\pu{1.41 gmL^–1}$ and the mass per cent of nitric acid in it being $69 %$.

I attempted to consider a 1L solution, and since $\pu{Density= \frac{Mass}{Volume}}$, obtained the mass of $\pu{1L}$ of the solution as $\pu{1410g}$.

I then attempted to acquire the mass of $\ce{HNO3}$, which I got as $\pu{972.9g}$ Then the number of moles of $\ce{HNO3}$ is $15.44$ moles. This makes the molarity of the solution $15.44$. Of course, this is far from correct, but I am unable to trace any mistake in my methods.

Any hints and answers are extremely appreciated.

Comment: What other methods and what other results?

Comment: Wikipedia: The concentrated nitric acid of commerce consists of the maximum boiling azeotrope of nitric acid and water. Technical grades are normally 68% HNO3, (approx 15 molar), while reagent grades are specified at 70% HNO3. The density of concentrated nitric acid is 1.42 g/mL

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your calculation (except maybe sig figs).

Comment: Dear OP, you are supposed to show your working so that the community can better gauge how it can help you. They are asking molarity from given mass %.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, although a more direct calculation would be:

$C_i=y_iC=\frac{x_i\require{cancel} \cancel{M}}{M_i}\frac{\rho}{\cancel{M}}=\frac{\left(0.69\right)\left(\pu{1410g/L}\right)}{\pu{63g/mol}}=\pu{15.44mol/L}$

Where:

$\,x_i$ is the mass fraction of $\ce{HNO3}$

$\,y_i$ is the mole fraction of $\ce{HNO3}$